# I have one adapter for wifi in my pi, how do I use this to connect to two wifi networks at the same time?

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

See title.............................

Comment: Please don't use the title to ask your whole question.

Comment: I attempted to edit the question and change the title to: "How can I use my Raspberry Pi with multiple wi-fi networks?" but was not permitted to do so.

Comment: This is actually an interesting question given the use of Raspberry Pi's in the field. I would very much like to understand how Vitalis encountered this issue. Please allow Vitalis to provide more detail.

Comment: Also, there are issues here about how other adapters might interact with the new wifi Pi's.

Comment: @OyaMist You should definitely be able to suggest an edit to this question; is there an error when you click 'edit'? Questions put 'on hold' can still be edited unless they're also locked. If you're able to improve this question and potentially get it reopened, feel free to give it a try.

Comment: My editing privilege was revoked becaiuse I made the horrible mistake of editing a moderators response. I'm a bad person, essentially.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics, there is no such thing.

Comment: OK. This is beating a dead horse, but my edit was rejected. The important part of the edit was for Vitalis to explain the use case. Dual simultaneous wifi is highly unusual. Please clarify.

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics one approach is to connect to two actioncams of different type to automate them

Comment: @Zurechtweiser but the actioncams could just use the same wifi with different IP?

Comment: **This is only on topic here if it is a question about the capabilities of the built-in wifi adapter on Raspberry Pi models.**  If it is a question about how to configure an external adapter that is capable of this (and some are), or how to figure out if an adapter has this capability, then presuming the context is Raspbian, it is a question that belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  If it is a question about whether it is in general possible, it belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @OyaMistAeroponics How?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. If you want to connect to two wireless networks at the same time, you need two adapters.

Comment: What do you base your knowledge on?

Comment: Experience? You connect to one wireless network, you automatically disconnect from the one you were connected to. I _assume_ it's because it's not possible to be connected at the same time to two different wireless networks with a single interface. Have you seen anyone hacking his/her way through to being connected to two networks?

Comment: Unless you have a pi which is already wifi enabled, such as the pi zero w or the pi 3.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is true, although it depends on the capability of the hardware.  You can certainly create two wifi interfaces with some adapters.  Most use cases described on the internet are about using one of them as a separate hotspot, but if that is possible, I don't see why it couldn't be connected to a separate WLAN instead.